# PHP: Upload images from client machine to the server

Tags: php, upload

I want to upload user images from client machine to server in php. 
The name of the image should be predefined.

Can any one tell me the php code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will the example from the manual page for [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) do?

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

Also see the chapter on [Handling File Uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) in the PHP Manual